# What is JMS?XML in JMS

Tags: jms

I have a very basic question.Please help me in understanding this.

What is actually JMS? How we need to configure it ?
Recently I heard from one of my colleague that in JMS,the XML tags will not be represented as "<" and ">" rather it would be as "ampersand+lt;" and "ampersand+gt;". Is that true?
I have tried to understand JMS concepts.But could not get a clear picture.
Could someone explain in simple way.

Comment: Have you tried to google JMS?

Comment: This is about as simple as it gets I think.  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncdq.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you have got the concept wrong, which is already pointed out in the comments... Anyway, you can put XML in a JMS message body and send that JMS message to a messaging engine. XML could be put in the JMS text message as is and no changes are required, like the one you have mentioned.

One of the reasons your colleague could have told you this is because the receiver of the JMS message might want the XML is some format.

JMS is a messaging API and XML is a markup language.